# What are these compiled x86-64 instructions and offset choices for?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm studying x86-64 assembly and for code to store a strings in a char* array;

```
char *name[2];  
name[0] = "Name";
name[1] = "null";
```

here's the assembly generated by the compiler (function prologue immediately precedes this):

```
mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
xor    %eax,%eax
lea    0x9689d(%rip),%rax
mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
lea    0x9689a(%rip),%rax
mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
```

To the best of my knowledge, I believe this copies the address of the supposed string into the `rax` register and then into the address space at an 8-byte negative offset from the `rbp` register.
The next three instructions, however, I'm lost out on. I believe the `xor    %eax,%eax` instruction, stores the value `0` in the `eax` register.

I'm not sure exactly what the `lea    0x9689d(%rip),%rax` and `lea    0x9689a(%rip),%rax` instructions are supposed to do. My guess is, copy the address stored in the `rip` (64-bit instruction pointer) register to the `rax` register? (with it's lower 32-bits now zero, thanks to the `xor` instruction?).

**First question**

Am I right or wrong with that assumption? And why the compiler chose those instructions?
(Recall, `rax` register held the address to the string)

**Second question**

And why didn't the compiler just copy the addresses of the string like it did in the first instruction `%fs:0x28,%rax`?

**Third question**

As local variables, the first string's address was stored at a negative 8-byte offset from the `rbp`. Why is the second string stored at offset of negative 24-bytes (16 bytes away from the first string instead of just 8), and I'm guessing `'/0'` character stored at offset of negative 32-bytes?

Comment: [`xor %eax,%eax` zeros the full RAX](//stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) and see [xor zeroing](//stackoverflow.com/q/33666617).  It's a GCC missed optimization that GCC includes that as part of `-fstack-protector-strong` to avoid leaving the stack cookie in a register, even though it's about to overwrite the register anyway with LEA, which also writes the whole destination.  It's just generating addresses in a PIE-compatible way. 
 [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)

Comment: Did you consider to use [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) to investigate? It shows which line in C translates to what instructions in assembly. -- Which compiler in what version and with which command line did you use?

Comment: The two string addresses (LEA results) are stored adjacent to each other.  To avoid the distraction of the stack cookie stuff with `%fs:0x28` while you're learning the basics, compile with `-fno-stack-protector`.

Comment: A `char *strings[2]` array won't contain any characters directly, only pointers.  The string literals have `'\0'` terminators, but there isn't a zero byte in the array of pointers (except as part of addresses, not a separate terminator.)  If you did `char str[] = "hello world";`, as a local var, then the compiler would store character data to the stack, including the implicit terminator.